# How to combine multiple text fields into textarea only when value is 1 or greater

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have this code for combine two text fields to single field and copy that as one row in textarea. For now, if I leave one row unfilled - it will leave empty row in my textarea.

I have tryed to write if > 0 / else statements to prevent empty rows in my textarea but let's face it, I'm just simple graphic designer with no codeing experience with jquery or javascript.

**HTML**

```
     1. 
     <label>Product </label><input type="text" id="text_1-1" value=""/>
     <label>Quantity </label><input type="text" class="sis" id="text_1-2" value=""/>
     <label>Combined </label><input class="yht" type="text" name="i1" id="text_1-3" value="" readonly/>

     <br><br>

     2. 
     <label>Product </label><input type="text" id="text_2-1" value=""/>
     <label>Quantity </label><input type="text" class="sis" id="text_2-2" value=""/>
     <label>Combined </label><input type="text" class="yht" name="i2" id="text_2-3" value="" readonly/>

     <br><br>

     3. 
     <label>Product </label><input type="text" id="text_3-1" value=""/>
     <label>Quantity </label><input type="text" class="sis" id="text_3-2" value=""/>
     <label>Combined </label><input type="text" class="yht" name="i3" id="text_3-3" value="" readonly/>

     <br><br>

     <textarea name="t" rows="3"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(".sis").change(function(){
$("#text_1-3").val($("#text_1-1").val() + " " + $("#text_1-2").val());
$("#text_2-3").val($("#text_2-1").val() + " " + $("#text_2-2").val());
$("#text_3-3").val($("#text_3-1").val() + " " + $("#text_3-2").val());


var values = "";

    // EASY WAY TO RUN THIS ONLY ON CHANGE AND IF QTY IS MORE THAN 0 ???

$("input.yht").each(function(i) {
    values += (i > 0 ? "\n" : "") + this.value;
});
$("textarea").val(values);
    });

    // SO TEXAREA WOULD NOT COPY ANY EMPTY LINES??
```

And here's [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8eXRx/217/)

(IF some reason I mess up givin link to fiddle again, you can find it from comments..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need is to check that the value is greater than one (accounting for the space that you're inputting by default):

```
if(this.value.length > 1)
```

Full code:

```
$(".sis").change(function(){
    $("#text_1-3").val($("#text_1-1").val() + " " + $("#text_1-2").val());
    $("#text_2-3").val($("#text_2-1").val() + " " + $("#text_2-2").val());
    $("#text_3-3").val($("#text_3-1").val() + " " + $("#text_3-2").val());


    var values = "";

// EASY WAY TO RUN THIS ONLY ON CHANGE AND IF QTY IS MORE THAN 0 ???

    $("input.yht").each(function(i) {
        if(this.value.length > 1)
            values += (i > 0 ? "\n" : "") + this.value;
    });
    $("textarea").val(values);
});

// SO TEXAREA WOULD NOT COPY ANY EMPTY LINES??
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6WA2/)

Comment: Can it really be so simple? Sure it seems to! Cannot wait to test this at my project!

Comment: Was so close to work for me! Actually I need the default value on qty to be 0 - and if it changes for something more and back again either copy combined files to textarea OR erase them from it. I made some chances, so here's the FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/G6WA2/6/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/G6WA2/8/ not a lot of code was changed, but be aware that it is functionally much different from my original answer.

Comment: That's it! Need some coffee for wakeing up and study those changes. Thank you!

Comment: So sorry for disturb again with this one, but I did encounter with a new problem. JQuery for collecting inputs to textarea stopped working, when I did put qty-selector inside div (critical for my layout-design). I have been trying everything what I can think of, can you find solution for this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/G6WA2/91/

Comment: Had to do a few more modifications, but your styling actually made it easier to get. http://jsfiddle.net/G6WA2/92/